# How do I Extrude Faces Along Normals, and also shrink in two other directions?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image: Plane]

[image: Extruded]

[image: Scaled]

I am extruding plane surfaces along surface normals by selecting the plane, then hitting Option-E (Alt-E), then selecting Extrude Faces Along Normals.

That is all fine, but I also want to shrink the object along the two local axes that are perpendicular to the Normal. So, as the plane gets thicker in one direction, it gets smaller in the other two directions.

I would be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Akin to inset then translate inset face along normal?

Comment: Truth be told, I do not know. If we call the Normal, the local Z, then I want to shrink in X and Y. The angles should remain right angles.
This works with Scale, I can edit in X,Y, and Z. But the Z does not exist until I have extruded the plane along its normal. As I do that, I want to also scale the two dimensions of the plane.

Comment: is this what you wanna do? https://youtu.be/UViI4VKy-Ww

Comment: @Chris Not quite. I want the sides to go in without the angles changing. So not a cuboid becoming a truncated pyramid, but a plane extruding into a cuboid and then scaling down in the two directions that are perpendicular to the normals.

Comment: can you show with two pictures what you want?

Comment: last try from me: do you want to change it like this after extrude: https://youtu.be/WEpuyZ1I2Ck

Comment: Yes, sure. I have added images to the question. 1. Plane. 2. Extruded. 3. Scaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Uniform scale around individual origins then extrude along normals.**

> Imagine the simple case: six square faces arranged as if they were the
> six faces of a cube. I would want to scale the 'top' surface in X and
> Y and not Z. I would want to scale the 'front' surface in X and Z but
> not Y. I would want to scale the sides in Y and Z and not X. And so
> on.

Here is the default cube, rotated arbitrarily in edit mode, and after applying edge split modifier to make each face a plane as described.

[image]

Uniform scale each by half <kbd>S</kbd> 0.5

Extrude along normal by 1 <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> 1

Notice the zero dimension along normal of each plane remains unaffected by scaling.

Comment: -To sum up for those who want to do this:    
-Starting from the planes. Select all in Object Mode.    

-Go to Edit Mode.    


-Choose Face Selection method, Select All.    


-Transform Pivot Point, Individual Origins.    


-Then Scale (S) and after, Extrude Faces along Normals (Option-E).    


-Thanks batFINGER and @Robin Betts Please edit my summary if needs be. Now to do it in Python!

Answer (score 3):

If you think about this one the other way round..

[image]

The <kbd>I</kbd> Inset operator has a 'Depth' setting, which you can adjust in its F9 panel.

If you need further adjustments, perpendicular to normals, for unconnected faces, you could set *Pivot* to 'Individual Origins', *Transform Orientation* to 'Normal', and scale in the per-face XY... <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: Oops, just read the commentary, but the second half might still apply.

Comment: Lol, thought exactly the same thing. Was also thinking  solidify modifier thickness driving scale.

Answer (score 2):

in edit mode:

1. extrude with <kbd>E</kbd> and move the mouse up (so you got 4 vertices) - you know this
2. Tap <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices
3. Tap <kbd>S</kbd> to scale
4. Tap <kbd>Shift Z</kbd> to scale only on x and y axis - > move your move to your desired scale

Comment: An  issue will be in scaling step if the face normal is not axis aligned.., which kinda warrants going in other order, uniform scale then extrude.

Comment: @batFINGER You correctly anticipate what I am trying to avoid, but I have problems with the uniform scale. I have a large number of these planes, all at different orientations. I can select them all and extrude along their normals. Easy.

Comment: If I try to do uniform scale on all the planes, I have a problem even if I pivot around individual origins. Imagine the simple case: six square faces arranged as if they were the six faces of a cube. I would want to scale the 'top' surface in X and Y and not Z. I would want to scale the 'front' surface in X and Z but not Y. I would want to scale the sides in Y and Z and not X. And so on.

Comment: If it helps, I will be doing this in Python so perhaps I can scale only along axes that are not zero?

Comment: @Chris Thanks! That is working nicely for one object. I need to spend some time to see if I can do this on many objects at the same time.